# Splitting a comma separated value into separate rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv that has the data (as a **Pandas** dataframe):

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       0.034   0.1
2,3,4   1.234   0.2
5       0.3     1.3
```

And I am trying to find a way to "expand" that second entry into multiple (three, in this example) lines. The final dataframe I am trying to achieve looks like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       0.034   0.1
2       1.234   0.2
3       1.234   0.2
4       1.234   0.2
5       0.3     1.3
```

**Does Pandas have any build in ways to do this?** Or am I left to resorting to creating a new dataframe and looping over the multivalued rows?

Comment: Look at the `explode` function in pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `explode`:

```
df.Col1 = df.Col1.str.split(',')                                                               
df.explode('Col1')
```

Output:

```
  Col1   Col2  Col3
0    1  0.034   0.1
1    2  1.234   0.2
1    3  1.234   0.2
1    4  1.234   0.2
2    5  0.300   1.3
```