# How to break down list of lists and insert into table by rows so that other columns remain same will using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have json file and I upload it.
One of the fields is name and the other is topics.
so each row has name and related topics.
The topics came back as list of lists and I turn into string to fit into cell but it's not what I need. I want that each row will have only name and 1 topic.
what's the right way to approach it so that I won't lose the name - topics connection ?

This is what I got:

```
`    name        topics
 0   John Adams   sports, education
 1   Ana smith    finance, Education
`
```

But this is what I need:

```
`      name        topics
 0   John Adams   sports
 0   John Adams   education
 1   Ana smith    finance
 1   Ana smith    Education
`
```

This is what I did:

```
 `import json
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  
  f = open('file.json')
  data = json.load(f)

  name = pd.DataFrame(data['name'].values(), columns=['name'])
  list_post = list(data['post'].values()) #this came back as list of lists
  list_post1 = list()

  #I wrote a function that turn into single string
  for i in range(0, len(list_post)):
         str_post = ",".join(list_post[i])
         list_post1.append(str_post)

  topics = pd.DataFrame((list_post1), columns=['Topics'])
  
  #then I created a single table
  df = pd.concat([name, topics], axis=1)
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841531/splitting-a-comma-separated-value-into-separate-rows-in-pandas

Comment: Can you please add sample json?